# Very simple For Loop question?

Tags: apex, list, loop

I have a FOR loop that doesn't appear to be running.

```
for (Integer i = 0; i > accountPackages.size(); i++){

            System.Debug('accountPackages.Check_Back__c = ' + accountPackages[i].Check_Back__c);
            System.Debug('Clone.Check_Back__c = ' + accountPackagesClone[i].Check_Back__c);

            if (accountPackages[i].Check_Back__c != accountPackagesClone[i].Check_Back__c){
                System.Debug('Queing Task: ' + i);
                PacksToSend.add(accountPackages[i]);
            }
        }
```

Assuming that accountPackages.size() equals exactly 1, this loop should run once and print the System.Debug statements to the debug log, right?

Comment: You have the > instead of <

Comment: @DougB But I thought that this would mean that it will run until 'i' is greater than accountPackages.size()?

Comment: It repeats the loop while the condition (i > accountPackages.size()) evaluates to true. But i is = 0, and accountPackages.size() = 1, so 0 > 1 == false. The loop doesn't run even once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No it will not show any logs as you have used ">" sign instead of
>   "<". It will check the size greater than 1 which is not as initial value is 0, hence it will not run not even once.